# Node js Express execute the single call more than once

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, double, backend, call

hi guys i am doing an insert with a control in the code params, but when hi send the request it execute it more than once and it insert the value(correct thing) and at the same time throwthe error.

here the code :

```
app.post('/insert', (req, res) => {

  let table = req.query.table;

  let campi="";

  for(var key in req.body) {
    if(req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      campi+=key+",";
    }
  }

  campi=campi.slice(0, -1);

  let valori ="";

  for(var key in req.body) {
    if(req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      valori+="'"+req.body[key]+"',";
    }
  }

  valori=valori.slice(0, -1);
  //riconosce se c'è il codice o meno 
  if(req.body.hasOwnProperty("codice")){
  console.log("eseguo controllo")
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM "+table+" where codice='"+req.body.codice+"'", (err, results) => {
    if (results.length==0) { 
      pool.query("INSERT INTO "+table+" ("+campi+") VALUES ("+valori+")", (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        } else {
          return res.send(results);
        }
      });
    } 
    else {
      res.send("attenzione non è possibile inserire due codici prodotto uguali");
    }
  });
}
//in caso non ci sia controlla l'id 
  
});
```

Comment: The entire request is executed more than once?

Comment: yeah, but i think now that i have done more test is a frontend problem

Comment: sounds like it, not enough info to help you with that though.

Comment: solve i will close issues thanks

Comment: If you've solved it outside of the information you provided here, then please delete your question.